# nls + warnOnly=TRUE + tryCatch

Tags: r

Делаю нелинейную регрессию с помощью функции `nls`.

В ряде случаев нет сходимости, и по умолчанию `nls` не возвращает никакой результат вообще, но с помощью параметра `warnOnly=TRUE` можно заставить `nls` возвращать в качестве результата то, что получилось на последней итерации до возникновения warning.

Однако если вызвать `nls` внутри `tryCatch` - на том же наборе точек, с теми же начальными параметрами и с `warnOnly=TRUE` - то результат перестает возвращаться. Почему так?

Comment: Дайте пример кода, когда `nls` ничего не возвращает.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась с помощью такой конструкции:

```r
    tryCatch({ 
        suppressWarnings(my_model <- nls(..., control=(warnOnly=TRUE)))
        return(my_model)
    }, warning = function(w) {}, 
       error = function(e) { return(NA) }, 
       finally = {}
    )
```

Я говорил о случаях «почти сходимости» или «как бы сходимости», т.е. какие-то итерации делаются (и бывает, что много), но в конце концов происходит termination before convergence с выдачей warning «фактор шага стал меньше заданного» или «сингулярный градиент». При этом `nls` без обертки в `tryCatch` выдавала результат, благодаря `warnOnly=TRUE`. А после заключения в обертку `tryCatch` - уже не выдавала. Почему, мне было непонятно. Оказывается, возникший warning «перебивал» результат. Если упаковать вызов `nls` внутрь `suppressWarnings`, получается то, что надо - результат выдается и при настоящей сходимости, и при «почти сходимости».

Руководство по R призывает нас использовать результат, полученный с помощью `warnOnly=TRUE`, не в качестве собственно результата :), а лишь для дальнейшего анализа (for further convergence analysis, but not for inference). Мне, собственно, оно для того и было нужно.